# How to load a graphml file with Netlogo NW extension

Tags: netlogo

I think there is a bug in the way nw:load-graphml works.

Take this graphml file with 3 nodes and 3 links of an undirected breed "parentals" and 2 links of a directed breed "diffusions" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns
    http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
<!-- Created by igraph -->
<key id="e_breed" for="edge" attr.name="breed" attr.type="string"/>
<graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">
    <node id="n0">
    </node>
    <node id="n1">
    </node>
    <node id="n2">
    </node>
    <edge source="n0" target="n1">
       <data key="e_breed">parentals</data>
    </edge>
    <edge source="n0" target="n2">
       <data key="e_breed">parentals</data>
    </edge>
    <edge source="n1" target="n2">
       <data key="e_breed">diffusions</data>
    </edge>
    <edge source="n0" target="n1">
       <data key="e_breed">diffusions</data>
    </edge>
  </graph>
</graphml>
```

when you load the file with nw:load-graphml what happens is that all "parentals" links are created, while "diffusions" are only partially created: only "diffusions" links that involves nodes not already linked by parentals links are created, while the others are skipped... is this a bug or an intended behavior in the load-graphml primitive?

this is a short net logo code to demonstrate:

```
extensions [nw]

undirected-link-breed [parentals parental]
directed-link-breed [diffusions diffusion]

to setup
   ca
   nw:load-graphml "prova.graphml"
   layout-circle turtles 10
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your NetLogo code the "diffusion" links are directed. Add directed = "true" attribute to diffusion links in the prova.graphml file:

```
<edge source="n0" target="n1">
   <data key="e_breed">parentals</data>
</edge>
<edge source="n0" target="n2">
   <data key="e_breed">parentals</data>
</edge>
<edge directed="true" source="n1" target="n2">
   <data key="e_breed">diffusions</data>
</edge>
<edge directed="true" source="n0" target="n1">
   <data key="e_breed">diffusions</data>
</edge>
```

I tried the corrected file and I think the links are OK now:

```
ask links [show self]
```

result:

```
(diffusion 2 1): (diffusion 2 1)
(diffusion 0 2): (diffusion 0 2)
(parental 0 1): (parental 0 1)
(parental 0 2): (parental 0 2)
```

### Edit:

In the current version of NW extension there are some [open issues](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/issues/129) in `load-graphml` function. I think it is a good idea to add some validation after importing the file to check the links' consistency. Maybe with `is-directed-link?` reporter for every "directed" links bread and also counting the links and comparing the expected number of links.

Comment: I accepted the answer because it works, but it's strange that it does... if I specify my diffusions links to be undirected, they are loaded anyway even if I added the directed="true" in the graphml file... I think something is still unclear, but thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: I agree. There are also some [open issues](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/issues/129) on dev site that are related to your issue.